# get user viewed products from his Cookie or Session in magento

Tags: magento, session-cookies

I want to get user viewed products in magento.Is it possible.like on start i will show empty data but as soon he view any product i want to get the products info and show it to user.Any clue or guidelines will be appreciated .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your modification in following class. Better you extend it.

> Mage_Catalog_ProductController -> viewAction()

```
$myValue = $productId;
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyValue($myValue);
```

To Retrieve:

```
$myValue=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyValue();
```

To Unset:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMyValue();
```

For Array:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('yourArray',array(1,2,3));
```

Other way. Here the $value can be array/object

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setXXX(serialize($value));
……
$value = unserialize(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getXXX());
```

Look [here](http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/anatomy-of-magento-session.html) for more info

Comment: how can i get products more then one ?